# SPO - /_vti_bin/lists.asmx returns Error 500

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, jquery, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am currently developing a news scroller/ticker in SharePoint Online (Office 365) and am using the follow script to access a list:

```
 var emptyResults = "<li>No current announcements</li>";

 $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "newsList",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
      completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        var itemCount = $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='rs:data']").attr("ItemCount");
                if (itemCount > 0) {
                    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                        var titleHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
                        $("#ticker").append(titleHtml);
                    });
                }
                else { $("#ticker").append(emptyResults); }
      }
});
```

Despite my list having an entry in it, the string 'No current announcements' gets written, suggesting itemCount is returning 0. Further debugging shows the Chrome Dev Console throwing the following error:

```
POST https://ontracsoftwaresolutions-8dca51b69a63f9.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/ntLive/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the listName correct?

Comment: /dev/Lists/newsList/ is the url for the list, so I would think so.

Comment: Leading from your extract from Chrome console, it seems your query gets executed agains /dev/ntLive, that is another web then you describes in the URL above :)

Comment: I'll look into it, I've very recently started SP work (couple of days) so I'm still a bit patchy. ntLive is the name of the project in Visual Studio 2012 if that makes a difference. Might be worth mentioning that the list and the application with the web app in are separate entities.

Comment: That should not affect your query! Is it possible that this code is executed from a subsite called ntLive?

Comment: Not sure if you caught my previous edit or not, but the application is called ntLive so the code would naturally run for /ntLive surely, since that's where the app is running?

Comment: I see nowhere you stated this was an app until now! Basically then, what your code is doing is trying to find a list called newsList in the AppWeb, and not in the HostWeb

Comment: Yes, slight oversight. Sorry about that. Trying to get my head around the 27,000 APIs and languages available and figure out which is going to be best for this solution. Thanks for your help. What is the best way to have a local SP app look for HostWeb?

Comment: Believe me, I know the feeling very well! Have a look here http://www.mavention.nl/blog/sharePoint-app-reading-data-from-host-web

Comment: Thanks for that link, strangely I can't seem to get that code to work. Still throws Err. 500 with /ntLive as the URL. I miss pulling/writing values from MySQL/PHP, that was always relatively simple :D.

Comment: I have managed to get it read both List.asmx files now but the /ntLive one still errors, not sure if that's stopping the other one from working properly.

Comment: You can add an answer with your solution, to help others in the future :)

Comment: I misread a URL I think, still seems to be broken. It's a relatively common thing to do I would of thought so I'm surprised about the lack of content on it.

Comment: The Mavention link has worked for me in the passed, but I used CLOM the whole way, and not SPServices. The problem might be that SPService still gets the wrong context.

Comment: Well, I've fixed the Error 500 problem by defining 'webURL:' as one of the SPServices properties. Managed to manipulate it to read the right lists.asmx file but itemCount still returns 0 despite there being a list item present. Seems to be a problem with the xData.ResponseXML line, I'll mess about for a bit with it. Many many thanks for your help you far. Great learning curve for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'webURL' property of SPServices to define the target site, this will aim it at the correct directory for lists.

I then replaced

```
.find("[nodeName='rs:data']")
```

With

```
.SPFilterNode("rs:data")
```

Which now seems to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

500 error happens when you try to get a list without spaces like you would with a /_vti_bin/ListData.svc call.

**Example:**

```
$scope.listCollection = [{
        "name": "Some List Title",
        "link": "SomeListTitle"
    }]
```

**listCollection.name works**

`/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Some%20List%20Title`

**listCollection.link does not**

`/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/SomeListTitle`

With the ListData.svc, you can get the xml data list both ways. But when fetching with SPServices, you will receive the 500 error and need to call the actual title.

Answer (score 0):

This error `/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx 500 (Internal Server Error)` happen due to wrong List Name:

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    webURL: "http://srv-abc",
    listName: "Workflow History",
```

I used `Workflow` list name but the actually the list name is `Workflow History`, that's why that error occurs.